# manipulate u64 type in Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, 64-bit

How can we manipulate the 32 bits high order and 32 bits low order of u64 type in Linux kernel. I tried this one, but the compiler reported a lot of warnings.

```
#define HI_BYTES(_a) (_a & 0xffffffff00000000)
#define LO_BYTES(_a) (_a & 0x00000000ffffffff)
/* _v is 32 bit value */
#define HI_BYTES_SET(_a, _v) do {_a = (_a & 0x00000000ffffffff) | (_v << 32)} while (0)
#define LO_BYTES_SET(_a, _v) do {_a = (_a & 0xffffffff00000000) | (_v)} while (0)
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank a lot!

Comment: u64? Perhaps you mean uint64_t? And do you really need to mess with macros instead of sticking in a small inline function and letting the compiler do its job?

Comment: it complained about the shift amount and the constant value 0xffffffff00000000 is too big. Thank everyone for taking time to answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect, for a start, that you're going to need qualifiers on those big honkin' hex numbers, something along the lines of:

```
0xffffffff00000000ULL
```

Unadorned integer constants are of the `int` type and that's probably not enough to hold the given values.

Other than that, you should *post* the warnings you're getting so we don't have to play the *Psychic Debugging* game :-)

---

And one other thing that may be problematic is `v << 32` for a 32-bit `v`. I'd probably opt for something like:

```
#define HI_BYTES(_a) (_a & 0xffffffff00000000ULL)
#define LO_BYTES(_a) (_a & 0x00000000ffffffffULL)
#define HI_BYTES_SET(_a, _v)\
    do {\
        u64 _xyzzy = _v;\
        _a = (_xyzzy << 32) | LO_BYTES(_a)\
    } while (0)
#define LO_BYTES_SET(_a, _v)\
    do {\
        u64 _xyzzy = _v;\
        _a = HI_BYTES(_a) | (_xyzzy)\
    } while (0)
```

This would make sure that everything is of the correct type before doing any bit shifting. Keep in mind that's untested, you'll have to confirm the correct behaviour.

---

But, of course, I missed the most obvious solution as put forward by Nicholas Knight in a comment. Get rid of the macros altogether. This is something far better handled by functions (marked inline if you wish but I rarely find this necessary since `gcc` optimises things insanely well anyway).

This way, the compiler can coerce data types and you don't run into the problems you invariably do with macros like `#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))` and `i = SQR(j++)`.

Answer (score 2):

As already said by others, the correct typedef is `uint64_t`. Constants of that type can be obtained by the predefined macro `UINT64_C`, e.g `UINT64_C(1)` will probably result in `1ULL`. But actually I don't think you need these.

*If* you really have a variable of that type (i.e with fixed width 64 and unsigned) shifting twice with 32 bit should always give the correct result. To only have the high order bits

```
((a >> 32) << 32)
```

The compiler will optimize this to the perfect assembler for your platform. (For gcc, compile with `-march=native` and check the assembler with `-S`.)

To be sure that this is really an `uint64_t` best is really as others said to have a function. This then converts to the right type(s), and you don't have to worry.

Such a small function *definition* belongs in a header file, so you *must* either declare it `inline` (or `static` if you must), otherwise you will encounter "multiply defined symbol" errors at link time.

To also have a symbol declared of your function somewhere, you'd have to put an `extern inline` declaration (not definition) in exactly one compilation unit.

Comment: `u64` is actually a valid type for the Linux kernel - not all compilers may provide a `uint64_t` type.